# Some photos are not syncing to iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, photos.app

When syncing photos through iTunes to my iPhone 4, I am finding that certain photos are not syncing. In one event there are 600+ photos yet only 200 are syncing across. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the **Photo Cache** may do the trick.

To do so, just:

1. From the Finder, choose Home from the Go menu.
2. Once there, open the Pictures folder and locate the iPhoto Library
   file. (For Aperture, this is called Aperture Library.)  If you have
   moved your iPhoto Library or Aperture Library to a different
   location, go to that location in Finder first.
3. Control-click the iPhoto Library or Aperture Library file and choose
   Show Package Contents from the shortcut menu.
4. In the next window, locate the iPod Photo Cache folder and drag it
   to the Trash. **Important:** Do not remove or modify any other file
   within the library package. Removing or modifying other files may
   cause data loss. Close the Finder window.

Extracted from [iTunes: Understanding the iPod Photo Cache folder.](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1314)